# OnCheckedChanged fires one time, when I click twice very fast

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using checkbox on asp.net webforms. But it fires one time, when I click twice very fast.
This is my code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="chk1" Text="Yes" CssClass="NormalBold" AutoPostBack="true"   OnCheckedChanged="chk1_CheckedChanged"/>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is server code.

```
protected void chk1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = chk1.Checked;
}
```

How it works now. For example, my checkbox is unchecked. I click twice very fast. As a result checkbox unchecked again, but chk1_CheckedChanged method performs only one time, and chk1.Checked value equals true.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want event fires as per you click on it...is it so?

Comment: Handle double-click event.

Comment: Yes, I want event fires as per I click.

Comment: But now it fires only once

Comment: It would fire on every time check changes because of your `AutoPostBack="true" `

Comment: I assume you have `AutoPostBack` on for the checkbox? If so, when you click the checkbox, you browser makes a `POST` request to the server, the server processes the request and sends back a reponse, which in turn the browser renders. This whole process takes time, so it's not reasonable to expect it to work flawlessly if you click very fast...